# Is it possible to use MVCContrib grid without exposing IQueryable from service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iqueryable, mvccontrib

I did not want to have a method that will return a IQueryable but I also want my paging queries to be executed in the database rather than in memory. 
This [article](http://thinkbeforecoding.com/post/2009/01/19/Repositories-and-IQueryable-the-paging-case) discusses how to expose only a subset of data via IQueryable.

I modified the GetRange method described in the article as below.

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetRange<TKey>(int page, int pageSize, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector, bool ascending )
    {

        IOrderedQueryable<T> sourceOrdered = null;
        sourceOrdered = ascending ? source.OrderBy(keySelector) : source.OrderByDescending(keySelector);

        return sourceOrdered.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

    }
```

And passing it contrib IPagination as below.

```
  var productPagedList = productList.GetRange(page ?? 1, 10, p => p.SupplierID, false)
            .AsPagination(page ?? 1, 10);
```

But the grid needs to know the total record count in order to render the pager properly.
Is there any way of getting the MVCContrib grid to work with a subset of IQueryable exposed from service layer this way? Or somehow feeding the total record count to it? Or any other tips?

Thanks